# Ifelse in R to change the last word in a vector

Tags: r

This is my vector: `myvector<-c("word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word")`

I want a `ifelse` command that tells the following: if myvector has **all** the same word I will change the last one to "notword" ELSE mantain the vector's word)

The resul should be this: `myvector<-c("word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "notword")`

Comment: Maybe this could be an option too(albeit too much computational work): `ifelse(all(myvector %in% "word"),
       myvector[length(myvector)]<-"notword",myvector)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to assign the last element (`length(myvector)`) to a different value

```
myvector[length(myvector)] <- "notword"
```

If we need a check as well

```
f1 <- function(vec) {
     if(length(unique(vec)) == 1) vec[length(vec)] <- "notword"
 vec
  }

f1(myvector)
#[1] "word"    "word"    "word"    "word"    "word"    "word"    "word"    "word"    "word"    "notword"

f1(myvector2)
#[1] "BRAZIL" "word"   "word"   "word"   "word"   "word"   "word"   "word"   "word"   "word"
```

Comment: Hahaha Many options!! Thanks again @akrun!

Answer (score 0):

We can compare `myvector` with first (or for that matter any) element of `myvector` and if `all` of them are same we can replace the last element with `"notword"`.

```
if (all(myvector == myvector[1])) myvector[length(myvector)] <- "notword"
```